# J2mod :I/O Exception- Failed to Read

Tags: java, modbus, rxtx

i want to utilize function code= 03, which means reading of holding registers , but i got some errors after connecting hardware.

I used j2mod-1.06 jar file and rxtx.I am using eclipse for it.In eclipse, during coverage session its this part shown red which means it not runned.

```
  catch (Exception exception) 
        {
            System.out.println("Not Run");
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }

        /* Read the first four holding registers */
        try 
        {
            slaveResponse = serialMaster.readMultipleRegisters(unitID, startingRegister, registerCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < slaveResponse.length; i++) 
            {
                System.out.println("reg" + i + " = " + slaveResponse[i]);
            }
        }
```

Here its code

```
import com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.facade.ModbusSerialMaster;
import com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.Modbus;
import com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.ModbusException;
import com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.procimg.Register;
import com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.util.SerialParameters;

public class ModbusMaster
{

/**
 * @param args
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        /* The important instances of the classes mentioned before */
        ModbusSerialMaster serialMaster = null; // the connection

        /* Variables for storying the parameters */
        String portname = "COM3"; // the name of the serial port to be used
        int unitID = 1 ; // the unit identifier we will be talking to
        int startingRegister = 10001; // the reference, where to start reading from
        int registerCount = 0; // the count of the input registers to read
        Register[] slaveResponse = new Register[registerCount];

        try 
        {
            /* Setup the serial parameters */
            SerialParameters parameters = new SerialParameters();
            parameters.setPortName(portname);
            parameters.setBaudRate(9600);
            parameters.setDatabits(8);
            parameters.setParity("None");
            parameters.setStopbits(1);
            parameters.setEncoding(Modbus.SERIAL_ENCODING_RTU);
            parameters.setEcho(false);

            /* Open the connection */
            serialMaster = new ModbusSerialMaster(parameters);
            serialMaster.connect();

        } 

        catch (Exception exception) 
        {
            System.out.println("Not Run");
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }

        /* Read the first four holding registers */
        try 
        {
            slaveResponse = serialMaster.readMultipleRegisters(unitID, startingRegister, registerCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < slaveResponse.length; i++) 
            {
                System.out.println("reg" + i + " = " + slaveResponse[i]);
            }
        } 

        catch (ModbusException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Close the connection */
        serialMaster.disconnect();

    }
}
```

Here is the error i got.

```
com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.ModbusIOException: I/O exception - failed to read
    at com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.io.ModbusRTUTransport.readResponse(ModbusRTUTransport.java:645)
    at com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.io.ModbusSerialTransaction.execute(ModbusSerialTransaction.java:189)
    at com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.facade.ModbusSerialMaster.readMultipleRegisters(ModbusSerialMaster.java:269)
    at ModbusMaster.main(ModbusMaster.java:53)
```

Comment: Hello Yash, Are you absolutely sure you have the connection parameters right? Before you get busy coding you might want to try to debug your Modbus device with something like [ModScan](https://www.win-tech.com/html/demos.htm) or [QModMaster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/) where you can play with the baud rate and register numbers etc. Note that you seem to be trying to read `registerCount = 0` zero registers? And you need to be very sure your `startingRegister = 10001` is correct too, is it a holding register or input register?

Comment: If you are not sure about all these details you might need to check the user manual of your Modbus device. You can post a link to the manual if you need help doublechecking.

Comment: thanks for your help, there was my fault in the digit of register number, i written reg. number like ```100001``` But it should be like this ```001``` and also in register count it should be 1 for one register reading . again thanks.

Comment: now if i want to read input register then what to do, beacuase it throws error like couldn't match type of register.

Comment: Hello Yash, if you want to read input registers instead of holding registers you need to use function `readInputRegisters(Int32, Int32, Array)`

Comment: Here, Issue is with the unitID.